# Como cambiar el color del menu de opciones

Tags: java, android

He voy a volver a cambiar la pregunta, porque el titulo del post creo que dice qeu lo que quiero **cambiar es el color del menu**, y no el color del boton.

No me voy a extender mucho a ve si asi se entiende mejor

Mi pregunta es como puedo cambiar el **color del menu de opciones** y el **color del fondo** del menu de opciones ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    for (int i=0; i<menu.size(); i++) {
        MenuItem mi = menu.getItem(i);
        String title = mi.getTitle().toString();
        Spannable newTitle = new SpannableString(title);
        newTitle.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, newTitle.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        mi.setTitle(newTitle);
    }
    return true;
}        

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_opciones, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.m_acerca:

            Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
            toast.setGravity( Gravity.CENTER,0,0);

            TextView tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            tv.setBackgroundColor( Color.RED);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            tv.setTextSize(20);

            Typeface t = Typeface.create("serif", Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
            tv.setTypeface(t);
            tv.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
            tv.setText("\"Documentos Versión 1.0\"");
            toast.setView(tv);
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();

            return true;

        case R.id.m_salir:
            onBackPressed();

        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Opción 2** para cambair el Color

Pero no consigo cambiar el color de fondo...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**colors.xml**

```
<resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#0099cc</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#0099cc</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
<color name="colorFondoMenuOpciones">#f2f2f2</color>
<color name="colorTextoMenuOpciones">#ffbb33</color>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
     <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyFondoMenu</item>
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/MyTextoMenu</item>

</style>

<!-- color fondo del Menu opciones -->
<style name="MyFondoMenu"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/colorFondoMenuOpciones</item>
</style>
<!-- color Texto del Menu opciones -->
<style name="MyTextoMenu">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorTextoMenuOpciones</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
  <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
  <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Gracias.

Comment: Hola @Webserveis, ya he editado el post, tenia dos partes, una de ellas se ha resuelto desde el link que pones, la otra del menu de opciones, ese de los tres punto, no se cambia, y el fondo de ese menu tampoco

Comment: Según lo [expresado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/141262/127) por el autor, con la pregunta que se marcó como duplicada, "*sí que puedo cambiar el **color del Boton**, pero eso no es lo que busco... yo que quiereo es cambiar el color al menu de opciones*"

Comment: Osea cambiarle el fondo. Mira este enlace https://www.techrepublic.com/article/style-androids-overflow-menu-using-this-sanity-saving-workaround/

Comment: Para otros revisores: hay bastante más info en el historial de revisiones, que pueden agregar a la pregunta en caso de que sea necesario

Comment: Hola, he puesto en el primer post el codigo que utilizo para el menu de opciones y el error que me sale al poner el codigo de esa pagina.

Comment: Te lo voy a mirar y te pondré alguna captura.

Comment: Gracias Diego, pero mira antes el segundo codigo que he puesto en el primer post, solo con eso he conseguido cambiar el color del texto, pero no se porque no cambia el color de fondo, igual de esa forma es mas facil y rapido.

Comment: He conseguido poner el fondo de color pero solo al Texto, y no todo al item. Me pasa lo mismo que a tí, no consigo cambiarlo desde el styles.xml

Comment: public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        for (int i=0; i<menu.size(); i++){
           
            newTitle.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE),
                    0, newTitle.length(),
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            newTitle.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN),
                    0, newTitle.length(),
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            elItem.setTitle(newTitle);
        }

Comment: Con el codigo que has puesto, me muestra unos errores, pero tambien ha probocado que otro codigo que tengo puesto en un menu me muestre otros errores, mira esta captura http://funkyimg.com/i/2CKLa.png

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73656/discussion-between-diego-l-o-l-and-socu).

Answer (score 1):

sencillo;

en el toolbarmain va a poner

```
 app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.PopupTheme"
```

[image: en el toolbarmain va a poner]

y en styles vas a añadir

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.PopupTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorPrimaryBackground</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/blanco</item>

</style>
```